# comparing columns of two dataframes and get the deviation point in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes:

```
> dput(DF1)
    structure(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"), .Dim = c(1L, 
    7L), .Dimnames = list("1", c("seq1", "seq2", "seq3", "seq4", 
    "seq5", "seq6", "seq7")))

> dput(DF2)
    structure(list(seq1 = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a"), seq2 = c("b", 
    "d", "d", "d", "b"), seq3 = c("c", "c", "c", "c", "c"), seq4 = c("e", 
    "e", "d", "d", "d"), seq5 = c("f", "f", "f", "g", "e"), seq6 = c("g", 
    "g", "g", "g", "g"), seq7 = c("g", "g", "g", "g", "g"), UserId = c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5")), .Names = c("seq1", "seq2", "seq3", "seq4", 
    "seq5", "seq6", "seq7", "UserId"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

These are the above two datasets which I want to compare for e.g User1 in DF2 has deviated to e ( instead of goind to d, he went to e). DF1 is my correct defined sequence.
    So in the end i need to make a dataframe the below requirements:

```
> dput(required_dataframe)
structure(list(UserID = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), Deviation = c("e", 
"d", "d", "d", "g"), Actual_sequence = c("d", "b", "b", "b", 
"f")), .Names = c("UserID", "Deviation", "Actual_sequence"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

For an instance that user1 deviated to point e (it should have gone to d). So for all users I need to calculate the deviation point along with the actual seq.
 Please find the attached images of DF1 ,DF2 and the required dataframe as well.

[DF1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VW8gc.png)

[DF2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBCRq.png)

[Required_dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCIf0.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get the two matrices to line up perfectly, you can compare them row-by-row and find out where they don't match. You can then find the first value in each row and use that as a selection:

```
sel <- cbind(
  seq_len(nrow(DF2)),
  max.col(t(t(DF2[seq_along(DF1)]) != c(DF1)), "first")
)
cbind(DF2["UserId"], Deviation=DF2[sel], Actual=DF1[sel[,2]])

#  UserId Deviation Actual
#1      1         e      d
#2      2         d      b
#3      3         d      b
#4      4         d      b
#5      5         g      f
```

The core of the comparison is this part, where you can see each cell being lined up:

```
t(DF2[seq_along(DF1)]) != c(DF1)

#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
#seq1 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#seq2 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#seq3 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#seq4  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#seq5  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#seq6  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#seq7 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```